# Angular-fullstack testing seems fragile?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I am new to angular and have recently been using 'yo angular-fullstack' to generate my framework.  This works well.  But today, I discovered an issue around the testing of a new directive.

When it was first generated - it was fine.  Then after examining the files with intellij, I found that a newly added newline in the template.html file caused the testing to fail.  This seems very strange... i.e. if there is an extra newline at the end of the testit.html file, the test should not fail.

Is it really necessary to do a trim() or some such in the test???  Any help would be appreciated.  I am new to angular, but I also want to make sure that I don't have an issue somewhere else in the code.  Have others seen this? Or is there an easy way to cause angular to dump out verbose/debug information?

Here is the relative section of the failing grunt test output:

```
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux) Directive: testit should make hidden element visible FAILED
Expected 'this is the testit directive
' to be 'this is the testit directive'.
```

The relevant files are:

testit.directive.js:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('trackerFooApp')
  .directive('testit', function () {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'app/testit/testit.html',
      restrict: 'EA',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      }
    };
  });
```

tesit.directive.spec.js:

```
'use strict';

describe('Directive: testit', function () {

  // load the directive's module and view
  beforeEach(module('trackerFooApp'));
  beforeEach(module('app/testit/testit.html'));

  var element, scope;

  beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
  }));

  it('should make hidden element visible', inject(function ($compile) {
    element = angular.element('<testit></testit>');
    element = $compile(element)(scope);
    scope.$apply();
    expect(element.text()).toBe('this is the testit directive');
  }));
});
```

testit.html:

```
<div>this is the testit directive</div>
```

Thanks for you help!

Comment: Probably not related but this - `module('app/testit/testit.html')` looks totally wrong. You don't have a module by that name.

Comment: Yes - this set of files is within the 'yo angular-fullstack' generated structure that separately crafts a client and a server section.  So the actual app is defined elsewhere and then injection 'magically' grabs this directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `toBe()` matcher uses a `===` comparison. For strings of text in HTML that may or may not have newlines, you probably want to use `toContain()`.

That being said, if you wanted to enforce exact format, `toBe()` or `toEqual()` is what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion toContain() works well.  I also utilized toMatch() with a regexp which makes sure that I fully understand the variance.

Answer (score 0):

To correct this issue, I modified:

```
expect(element.text()).toBe('this is the testit directive');
```

->

```
expect(element.text().trim()).toBe('this is the testit directive');
```

which solves the issue... and makes it clear that the extra newline is the issue in this case.  I hope this helps someone else who is new to this like me :-)